# Java Rest Assured - how to sort JSON response

Tags: java, json, rest, sorting

Java Rest Assured - how to sort JSON response

```
[
   {
    "name": "firstName", 
    "age": 22 
   },

   {
    "name": "AnotherName", 
    "age": 33
   }
]
```

I have list of many objects - after deserlizlization to Java objects I want to SORT it based on age value - so the first shoulb be object with age 33.

Comment: Do you have a POJO that represents the deserialized object?

Comment: yes, I have java class with fields: String name, int age (getters and setters)

Answer (score 0):

First, create a POJO representing the deserialized object:

```java
@Data
public class YourObject {
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

Then you can deserialize your JSON string to `List<YourObject>` by using Jackson's `ObjectMapper`

```java
List<YourObject> list = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<YourObject>>(){});
```

Then use `List.sort`  and `Comparator` to sort this list by descending order.

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(YourObject::getAge, Collections.reverseOrder()));
```